# 3 Events, probability of 2 being a specific value?

Tags: probability, binomial-distribution

I have a probability problem but maths is not my strongest field. I usually use online calculators but I have a specific problem. I have three variables in my code which randomly generate a number between 0 to 255.

```
a = 0 to 255
b = 0 to 255
c = 0 to 255
```

All three variables are generated at the same time, I am trying to work out the chance of either one of them being 0, or two of the variables being 0.

I have the probability of one of these variables being 0 as a single event = 0.39%

Then based on this:

```
Chance of all 3 variables being 0 = 0.0000059%
Chance of at least one variable out of three being 0 = 1.17%
Chance of at least two variables out of three being 0 = ????
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: [Binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The probability of (exactly) two of them being $0$ is $$\binom 3 2 \left(\frac 1 {256}\right)^2 \left(\frac {255} {256}\right),$$ while the probability of all of them being $0$ is $$\left(\frac 1 {256}\right)^3.$$

Now, observe that the result you are looking for is simply the sum of these two probabilities.

Also, as mentioned in a comment, your problem is closely related to the [binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution).

Comment: Instead of “any two,” I’d write “exactly two.”

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Yeah, I see the ambiguity there. Thanks for that. I have edited my answer accordingly!

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Thank you! Well written solution, this will also help me with some similar problems I am going to face shortly in my code. Have a good day.

Comment: @WilliamGarner not my solution, though.

Comment: @EthanMark Oh, my apologies I got the usernames mixed up. Whoops, thanks Ethan.